# ADF : How to check if JSON array contains particular string

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Here is some sample data provided by a cosmosdb which contains JSON :

```
[
{
    "Name":"ABC",
    "ID":20,
    "Category":"IT",
    "training_cycles": [
        "Jan 01, 2022 → Jun 30, 2022",
        "Jul 01, 2021 → Dec 31, 2021"
    ]
},
{
    "Name":"John",
    "ID":25,
    "Category":"Comp",
    "training_cycles": [
        "Jan 01, 2022 → Jun 30, 2022"
    ]
},
{
    "Name":"XYZ",
    "ID":23,
    "Category":"HR",
    "training_cycles": [
        "Jan 01, 2022 → Jun 30, 2022"
    ]
}
]
```

Id like to ask azure data factory to select items which contain "Jul 01, 2021 → Dec 31, 2021" within "training_cycles".

So far, in my data flow, i have selected all my items and filtered to only see training_cycles... so my data only has 1 "column" called training_cycles and many items which contain these training_cycles.

I tried filtering with :

```
contains(training_cycles, "#training_cycles" == "Jul 01, 2021 → Dec 31, 2021")
```

but it selects all the data instead of only the items which contain the right data.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue.

My sample json

```
[
{
    "Name":"ABC",
    "ID":20,
    "Category":"IT"
},
{
    "Name":"John",
    "ID":25,
    "Category":"Comp"
},
{
    "Name":"XYZ",
    "ID":23,
    "Category":"HR"
}
]
```

Source Settings Data preview

[image]

Then I used `Filter Row Modifier`. Here In Filter On condition I used `Name==’ABC’`. In your case you can use  `training_cycles == "Jul 01, 2021 → Dec 31, 2021"`

[image]

Expected Result in Data preview

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, the example is so close! The initial problem is that training_cycles is a sub tree...

can you please try it like this : 

[
{
    "Name":"ABC",
    "ID":20,
    "Category":"IT",
    "training_cycles": [
        "Jan 01, 2022 → Jun 30, 2022",
        "Jul 01, 2021 → Dec 31, 2021"
    ]
},
{
    "Name":"John",
    "ID":25,
    "Category":"Comp",
    "training_cycles": [
        "Jan 01, 2022 → Jun 30, 2022"
    ]
},
{
    "Name":"XYZ",
    "ID":23,
    "Category":"HR",
    "training_cycles": [
        "Jan 01, 2022 → Jun 30, 2022"
    ]
}
]